# How do I export my built AEM site with all the content and assets for someone else?

Tags: java, maven, adobe, aem

I am quite new to AEM. I am sharing a git repository with another colleague and both of us can pull and push commits. If I change the html for a component, we both will have the code.
My question is: Let's say I created
a page and included copy for it and a couple of images and components. Is there a way for me to export the page I built on my local AEM instance for my colleague to have it or should they build this page as I did step by step? I need to save time.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Package Manager for content transfer between instances: https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-65/administering/contentmanagement/package-manager.html

Comment: Do content packages retain the live copy links set up?

Answer (score 1):

First, go to this URL "http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/index.jsp"

1. click on Create Package Button in the topbar and enter details and click ok.[step1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qd2rd.png)
2. Now, click on Edit and the filter->Add Filter now click on the search icon and select your page from the project and click ok and then save.[step2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6OAx.png)
3. now click on Build and now you can download. and you can import this into another project.[step3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXoCn.png)
4. for more detils  go to = https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-65/administering/contentmanagement/package-manager.html?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

You can create a package of your page and the required images and share with others. Packages can be easily created in the crxde. Packages or package manager can be used for multiple purposes like moving content from lower environment to higher, taking a backup of your content and many things.

Answer (score 0):

The Package Manager is likely the solution here. Take into account that for a few pages and assets it is very handy, but it is recommended to create proper filters and exclude assets renditions to reduce the package final size as the site (or testing content) grows.